# why are the averages time of 3 algorithms negative?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, analysis, performanceanalytics

I have to use arrays of sizes ranging from 10000 to 50000 with step size 10000, give the same input to all three algorithms, and for each input repeat the execution 100 times, measure the execution in nanoseconds
(using System.nanoTime()), and report the average time in milliseconds.
that's what I did below but some of the averages are negative I don't know why?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort{

   public static void main(String[]args){

      double[] arr5 = new double[50000];

      for(int i=0;i<arr5.length;i++)
         arr5[i] = Math.random();

      selectionSort(arr5,10000);
      bubbleSort(arr5,10000);
      quickSort(arr5,10000);

      selectionSort(arr5,20000);
      bubbleSort(arr5,20000);
      quickSort(arr5,20000);

      selectionSort(arr5,30000);
      bubbleSort(arr5,30000);
      quickSort(arr5,30000);

      selectionSort(arr5,40000);
      bubbleSort(arr5,40000);
      quickSort(arr5,40000);

      selectionSort(arr5,50000);
      bubbleSort(arr5,50000);
      quickSort(arr5,50000);
   }

   public static void selectionSort(double [] A,int n){
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Algorithm 1");
      for(int s=0;s<100;s++){
         long arr[] = new long[100];

         long startTime = System.nanoTime();

         for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            int min = i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
               if(A[j] < A[min])
                  min=j;}
            double tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[min];
            A[min]=tmp;}

         long endTime = System.nanoTime();

         arr[s] = endTime - startTime;
      //System.out.println(arr[s]);
         sum+=arr[s];
      }
      System.out.println("Average:" + ((sum/100)*Math.pow(10,-6)));

   }

   public static void bubbleSort(double A [],int n){
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("\nAlgorithm 2");
      for(int s=0;s<100;s++){
         long[] arr = new long[100];

         long startTime = System.nanoTime();

         for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++){
               if(A[j]<A[j+1]){
                  double tmp = A[j];
                  A[j] = A[j+1];
                  A[j+1] = tmp;}}}

         long endTime = System.nanoTime();

         arr[s] = endTime - startTime;
      //System.out.println(arr[s]);
         sum+=arr[s];
      }
      System.out.println("Average:" + ((sum/100)*Math.pow(10,-6)));

   }

//algorithm 3
   public static void quickSort(double A [],int n){
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("\nAlgorithm 3");
      long[] arr = new long[100];

      for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
         long startTime = System.nanoTime();

         Arrays.sort(A,0,n-1);

         long endTime = System.nanoTime();

         arr[i] = endTime - startTime;
      //System.out.println(arr[i]);
         sum+=arr[i];
      }
      System.out.println("Average:" + ((sum/100)*Math.pow(10,-6)));

   }

}
```

Comment: Another problem is that you're creating the array:  `long arr[] = new long[100];` inside the for-loop...

Answer (score 5):

The variable `sum` used for your calculations is of type `int`. As you increase `sum` it overflows due to the result of `endTime - startTime` being quite a large value. When the overflow of `sum` occurs its value goes back to the minimum value (which is negative) and continues to increase again.

**Fix**: change the type of `sum` to `long`.

Another comment

Your arrays called `arr` seem redundant as they're not used in the calculation and are reset with each loop.

For example, in your `bubbleSort()` method. You declare and initialise the array `long[] arr = new long[100];` inside the `for` loop: `for(int s=0;s<100;s++)`.

Now the only purpose of this array `arr` at present is to store the result of `endTime - startTime` at index `s`, which is then used to increase `sum` (`sum+=arr[s];`).

If that's its only purpose, why not just do `sum += endTime - startTime` and remove the array completely?

If you did infact intend to keep track of all the results in this array, then you should move `long[] arr = new long[100];` outside of the `for` loop `for(int s=0;s<100;s++)`, as currently it is redeclared and initialised with each iteration.

To demonstrate consider this small example which replicates what you are doing in `bubbleSort()` and the other methods:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    arr[i] = (i + 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

The output is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

If the array is declared prior to the loop, then the behaviour would make more sense:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = (i + 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

In this case the output is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Print the contents of your array `arr` to the console in the `for` loop and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yea I just figured out the int mistake, but I don't get what you mean by reset each loop what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @user7150641 please read the entire answer, he suggested using `long`